# Application run failed

Tags: spring-boot

Please help who know spring boot

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin\java" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=55790 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=55791:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-32.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\rt.jar;D:\cargofin\target\classes;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.10.0\log4j-to-slf4j-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.10.0\log4j-api-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.25\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.19\snakeyaml-1.19.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-json-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.6\jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.6\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.6\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.6\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.10.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.10.Final.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.4\classmate-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.6\jackson-core-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.13\aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.2.17.Final\hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.2.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.22.0-GA\javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.3.Final\jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.1.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\javax.transaction-api\1.2\javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.0.8.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.0.8.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-aspects-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-devtools\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-devtools-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.5\gson-2.8.5.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\jstl\1.2\jstl-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\2.7.9\HikariCP-2.7.9.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\sqlserver\mssql-jdbc\6.5.0.jre8-preview\mssql-jdbc-6.5.0.jre8-preview.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Администратор\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar" myapp.SpringBootApplication
    15:22:41.243 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
    15:22:41.247 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter/target/classes/]
    15:22:41.248 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/D:/cargofin/target/classes/]


  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.3.RELEASE)

2018-08-15 15:22:43.609  INFO 6868 --- [  restartedMain] myapp.SpringBootApplication              : Starting SpringBootApplication on ADmin-PC with PID 6868 (D:\cargofin\target\classes started by Администратор in D:\cargofin)
2018-08-15 15:22:43.611  INFO 6868 --- [  restartedMain] myapp.SpringBootApplication              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-08-15 15:22:43.889  INFO 6868 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7c07ce: startup date [Wed Aug 15 15:22:43 AZT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-08-15 15:22:45.021  WARN 6868 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [myapp.SpringBootApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
2018-08-15 15:22:45.130 ERROR 6868 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [myapp.SpringBootApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:184) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:316) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at myapp.SpringBootApplication.main(SpringBootApplication.java:24) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:169) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:393) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:318) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:202) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:170) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:158) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    ... 26 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
**strong text**
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question. Hint dumping a stacktrace and expecting an answer isn't a good way of asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your javax.servlet dependency is missing try to add:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The same exception

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me after including the main class in a package.
Please look into:
[o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54458324/o-s-boot-springapplication-application-run-failed/61041236#61041236)
for further updates on what all versions I used.